# Jetpack Compose - Capture KeyDown Key Event In Text Field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When i add onKeyEvent on my TextField and press keyboard button i can handle only KeyUp event, but not KeyDown. Actually i need detect long press on ENTER key, may by there is an easier way

```
modifier = Modifier
              .onKeyEvent {
                    when (it.type) {
                        KeyUp -> println(" KeyUp Pressed")
                        KeyDown -> println(" KeyUp Pressed")
                        Unknown -> println("Unknown key type")
                        else -> println("New KeyTpe (For Future Use)")
                    }
                    false
                }
```

Logs `V/InputMethodManager: dispatchKeyEventFromInputMethod: KeyEvent=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0, eventTime=344884797, downTime=344884797, deviceId=-1, source=0x0, displayId=0 } V/InputMethodManager: dispatchKeyEventFromInputMethod: KeyEvent=KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0, eventTime=344884797, downTime=344884797, deviceId=-1, source=0x0, displayId=0 }`

Answer (score 1):

Use onPreviewKeyEvent :
Working keydown,
first called

onKeyEvent :
not working key down
not first called

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need it anymore, but you have to check if your type is equal to the specific `KeyEventType`

```
    Modifier.onKeyEvent {

        if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
            // your code
        }

        if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyUp) {
            // your code
        }

        true
    }
```

Comment: I only see KeyEventType.KeyDown come through when using onPreviewKeyEvent, not onKeyEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/handling-interactions

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
    interactionSource.interactions.collect { interaction ->
        when (interaction) {
            is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                // do something
            }
            is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}

...
// add "interactionSource" to a clickable view
modifier
    .clickable(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
    ) {
        // do something
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `nativeKeyEvent`. E.g.:

```
  modifier = modifier
        .onKeyEvent {
            if (it.nativeKeyEvent.action == ACTION_DOWN) {
                doStuff()
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't help